# Ubuntu 16.04.03 LT will not connect over HTTP/HTTPS but will ping

Tags: ubuntu, networking, apt, wget, ping

I am having a weird situation with networking. Essentially, ping works fine but basically any HTTP/S transport fails, including APT. I'm guessing I have a networking problem somewhere but I'm not sure how to fix it. I am getting a "Cannot initiate the connection" with APT error.

Unfortunately, apparently copying and pasting the code from my terminal is causing it to be consider as spam, so I had to take a screenshot. Sorry!

[image: Picture showing PING working but others not]

Comment: I tried this with no success...

sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update

Also, I am SSH'ing into this machine so it is connected to the internet.

Comment: given that your (failing) `wget` invocations use *IPv4*, i don't think that `Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` would do anything good here. anyhow, check your proxy settings.

Comment: Check firewall and proxy. Or might be you have a restricted network (corporate firewall or alike)?

Comment: No luck so far...
- echo '$http_proxy' didn't reveal anything...
- sudo ufw status reveals it is disabled
- no corporate firewall

Interesting, apache2 is working and the site responds to incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: Further information... 

php-fpm7.0 is not working - indicating that perhaps Apache2 cannot communicate with php-fpm.